# Using ST_GeomFromGML in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, wfs, gml

Im working with the SQL query composer in QGIS to add a WFS layer. This returns 28 features:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Enkelbestemming 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geometrie, 
ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(55186 361094)'), 100)
```

But this returns nothing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Enkelbestemming 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geometrie, 
ST_GeomFromGML('<gml:Point srsName="EPSG:28992"><gml:coordinates>55186,361094</gml:coordinates></gml:Point>'), 100)
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Is the SRID of the layer "Enkelbestemming" EPSG:28992?

Comment: as @user30184 hinted, both geometries need to be in the same spatial reference or you'll get nothing from st_dwithin.

Comment: Think to use : st_transform
In order to convert CRS